# Remove SeparatorInset on iOS 8 UITableView for Xcode 6 iPhone Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios8, xcode6

I found a weird white space on `UITableView` for **iPhone 6 Simulator** (iOS 8) on Xcode 6 GM. I have tried to set the `SeparatorInset` from both storyboard and also the code, but the white space is till there.

The following code works on iOS 7 but not on iOS 8 (iPhone 6 simulator).

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```

I attached screenshot below:

[image: iPhone 6 Simulator weird white space on tableview]

I am using AutoLayout by the way. I hope someone can show me a way to remove the weird white space on the `TableView`.

Comment: I got a working reference from this blog 
http://datacalculation.blogspot.in/2014/10/2-steps-to-use-uitableviewcell.html

Comment: See my answer in [iOS 8 UITableView separator inset 0 not working](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33297967/616764)

Comment: This answer may help others with the same issues: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38206546/1137246

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Thanks Student for pointing me to the right direction with the comment "*Try this self.myTableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero*;" This line of code will only work on iOS 8 because **layoutMargins** is only available from iOS 8. If I run the same code on iOS 7, it will crash.

> ```
> @property(nonatomic) UIEdgeInsets layoutMargins
> Description   The default spacing to use when laying out content in the view.
> Availability  iOS (8.0 and later)
> Declared In   UIView.h
> Reference UIView Class Reference
> ```

[image]

Below is the right answer to solve this weird white space by setting the `tableview layoutMargins` and `cell layoutMargins` as `UIEdgeInsetsZero` if it exists (for iOS 8). And it will not crash on iOS 7 as well.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

   if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
   }
}
```

See the screen shot below:-

[image]

Comment: Thanks for making this compatible with iOS7 as well. Works great on iOS8

Comment: I found, to get this to work for iOS 8, I had to reload the table view in ViewDidAppear.

Comment: I got a working reference from this blog 
http://datacalculation.blogspot.in/2014/10/2-steps-to-use-uitableviewcell.html

Comment: Works. I'd be really interested if there's a solution using appearance and rip this code out of the table implementation

Answer (score 48):

Try to create a UITableViewCell class category and add this getter

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)layoutMargins {
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

in iOS7 this will not be called cos there's no this property in SDK，and will not cause any crash；
in iOS8 this will be called every time you use the cell

It works for me

Comment: This worked great for me.  This is all you need to add if you have custom cells.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for when I implemented custom cells.

Comment: This one really needs more upvotes. Works perfectly in my case.

Comment: Simple, elegant and global solution! There is no need to add tha layoutMargin settings to each UITableView through entire project - just add a category and all will be ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

My solution with just three lines of code:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)row{
    //
    // ... your code ...
    //
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins)]){
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

IOS8 introduce a new concept named **[Configuring Content Margins](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/layoutMargins)** , a new property named **[layoutMargins](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/layoutMargins)** is also introduced , for the details of the property , please refer to the Apple Doc . The type of **layoutMargins** is **UIEdgeInsets** , by default the value is {8,8,8,8} . To remove the seperator line of TableView in IOS8 , in addition to set `tableView.seperatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero` , you must also do as  :

First define the macro

```
#define isIOS8SystemVersion (NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1)
```

In the UITableViewDelegate method add :

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
         static NSString *reuseId = @"cellReuseID" ;
         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseId];
         if(!cell){
             cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:reuseId];     
         if(isIOS8SystemVersion){   
             cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
             cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins =NO ;
         }

    }
```

Doing these will remove the seperator line . You can also do as follow :

```
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    if(isIOS8SystemVersion){
         tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero ;
    }
```

and in the UITableViewDelegate method add :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *reuseId = @"cellReuseID" ;
     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseId];
     if(!cell){
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:reuseId];     
     if(isIOS8SystemVersion){   
         cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
     }
}
```

Comment: for me, cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO; is the key.

Answer (score 12):

In my case in Xcode 6.2, in addition to Will Q's answer, I have to go to Main.storyboard > select the UITableViewCell > Attributes Inspector. Change Separator dropdown list from Default Insets to **Custom Insets**. Change the left inset from 15 to 0.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Workaround for iOS 7 & iOS 8

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, cell.frame.size.width, 0.0f, 0.0f); 
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Short and sweet! :) Works 100%

Comment: None of the other answers worked for me, agree with @emotality

Comment: Agree that this is the correct answer. Also works flawlessly in iOS 9.    Other answers mix the separation line between cells with the separation lines at the end of sections

Answer (score 9):

In iOS8 you have to set the Inset **both** on Row and on Table level.

Row level in the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins)]){
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false;
}
```

Table level in the viewDidLoad:

```
[tableReference setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

After that it is a good idea to CLEAN your project. On some occasions I noted that these changes were not directly introduced in the executable App in the simulator.

Answer (score 5):

for iOS 8

try by setting  `cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

Comment: I have tried that and like I mentioned above, this method only works on iOS 7.

Comment: Try this self.myTableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the white line, but keep separator inset as it is, just set the cell.backgroundColor to the tableView backgroundColor. Just setting the cell.contentView.backgroundColor does not make the problem disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried many ways, none of them work but this one works for me.

[image: WORK FOR ME]

Answer (score 0):

Add startup images for iPhone 6 and Plus. Before the images are added the phone is running in scaling mode, i.e. older Apps get scaled to fit the new screen sizes. This may be causing the lines.
The new images are Retina HD 5.5 (iPhone6Plus) 1242x2208 and Retina HD 4.7 (iPhone6) 750x1334.

Comment: Actually, I am re-developing the app using XCode 6 Beta by implementing the Autolayout since a few weeks ago. So, it is practically a brand new app. Anyway, I have found the answer above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See [iOS 8 UITableView separator inset 0 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working/25877725#25877725)

Basically, you need to set both the cell.layoutMargin as well as the tableView's layoutMargin. YMMV, but I had to set the table view up in layoutSubviews before it would work!

Answer (score 0):

To make your UITableView separator insets to zero for both iOS7 and iOS8, instead of making a change in the code, make a change in the xib for the UITableView by changing the View->Mode->Aspect Fill.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: The Content Mode flag on a UITableView is used to determine how a view lays out its content when its bounds change.  The AspectFill will fill the tableViewCell out to it which will fill out the entire view instead of the added margins that were put in for IOS8.  More information on the ContentModes can be found in the Apple docs  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode

Answer (score 0):

I have static `UITableView` and wanted to shift the margin of a cell separator to the left edge.

Thanks to the above answers, this was my solution

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // needed to shift the margin a specific cell to the left edge
    if indexPath.section == 3 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: works only wit cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0), thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```