# Autolayout metrics differs between iOS 7 & 8 for UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that contains only one `UILabel` that holds a static text, I wrote two `Autolayout` constraints in code (using the regular way but not visual format) to pin the leading and top edges of the label to the container view of the cell, and it works on both `iOS 7` and `iOS 8` devices but with a weird problem in `iOS 8`: the top edge of the label is 12 pixels far from the top edge of the container view (and this is the correct and expected metrics) but in `iOS 8` is more than that, about 20 pixels, and the same shifting happens for the leading edge of the label.

what does this means ? is that related to `UIKit` changes between `iOS 7` and `iOS 8` for `UITableViewCells` which now contains a hidden `scrollView` in its hierarchy ?

p.s. the constraints are :

```
 constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.myLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier: 1.0 constant:12];
                [self.contentView addConstraint:constraint];


 constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.myLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:12];
                [self.contentView addConstraint:constraint];
```

any help would be highly appreciated ...

Comment: Try to set `label.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0, 0, 0)`, in iOS 8 its default margin is 8pt.

Comment: tried it it didn't change anything

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762723/remove-separatorinset-on-ios-8-uitableview-for-xcode-6-iphone-simulator

Comment: Show your project so we can know how to fix it.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't share it, it's a big project

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to add a specific constraints to an imageview manually at runtime, the result was a different Leading alignment in iOS7 (completely attached to the left side of the cell) and iOS8 (correctly aligned). The issue was not only in the cell but even in the UITableView constraints:

1) check your tableview leading and trailing constraints, must be like those ones:

[image]

Both for Leading and Trailing, sometimes when you add manually a table view to the view controller the natural way to align the tableview's left and right sides is set it to -16, that works well for iOS 8 but not for iOS 7.

2) If you amend/add some constraints check if the cell respond to setLayoutMargins (only iOS8) and in case change the constraint's constant value:

```
CGFloat leftMargin = 8.0;
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    leftMargin = 0.0;
}

[self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.userImageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeadingMargin multiplier:1 constant:leftMargin]];
```