# iOS 8: Remove Underline from UITableViewRowAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, swift

I've been banging my head against the wall with this one, so maybe someone here has done this before.

Anyway, I'm trying to change how the delete button looks in my UITableView, and I've got it mostly figured out. I'm changing it by setting the background Color to a UIImage of what I actually want it to look like.

Apparently, though, a UITableViewRowAction has a faint grey line under it, and I can't figure out how to make this disappear. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. There's a link to what I'm talking about here:

[image]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

This is a separator line of `UITableView`. You can remove it by setting it's style as None.

Objective C:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Swift:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
```

Initially separator line is not visible, because I think height of image or view added in cell is more than cell height.

And that's why while you swipe separator line is visible. If you are testing in Simulator than use **Debug > Color Blended Layers** of Simultor. Which is helpful to track overlapping views.

[image]

### Edit:

iOS 8.0 introduced **layoutMargins** for `UITableView`. So it may be possible reason for that also.

Check out this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762723/remove-separatorinset-on-ios-8-uitableview-for-xcode-6-iphone-simulator) for more information.

It explains to clear layout margins by setting `cell layoutMargins` as `UIEdgeInsetsZero`.

Comment: That's not it actually, I thought that too at first :/ I've already done that, and trust me, I can see the separators if I don't, they're not covered up. Thanks though!

Comment: 'Delete' button looks like custom here. So check that line is visible due to custom view.

Comment: It doesn't look to be a separator line, based on [this](http://imgur.com/2kac5F1). The custom view is actually a UIImage being using as a background image, and it's simply white. The behavior if it doesn't fill the view is to tile, so the line can't come from that. I really think it's a part of UITableViewRowAction, but I can't find where it is.

Comment: From your reference image it is clear now that it's not overlapping view line. Let me check what other cause here can be.

Comment: Do you specified any footer view or table footer view. Some times footer view lines also appears. In earlier iOS version many had faced bottom line issue any it was due to footer view.

Comment: Thanks so much for looking. I added this code and it's still the same. Do I need to set an edge other than zero? func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        
        tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try this on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Method

```
for iOS lower versions

 if(indexPath.row != self.newCarArray.count-1){
   UIImageView *line = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 2)];
   line.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   [cell addSubview:line];
  }
```

for iOS 7 upper versions

```
 if (indexPath.row == self.newCarArray.count-1) {
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, cell.bounds.size.width);
 }
```

Comment: Do you mean in the cellForIndexPath method?

Comment: in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: How? Neither cell now indexPath.row exist yet

Comment: Sorry for type mistake

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work. I don't think it's a separator.