# Why there is still margin on UITableView even after I set constrain to 0

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I just bought a book and learn programming IOS in Swift. I want to create a table view list like snapchat: 
[image]

Then I set the all of the constrain of the UITableView to [image]0:

However, there is still a margin on left of the table, why?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762723/remove-separatorinset-on-ios-8-uitableview-for-xcode-6-iphone-simulator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search for Separator inset in interface builder after clicking on the `UITableView`

[image: Before]

And change it to Custom. Now you can set the Left Inset to 0

[image: After]

### Objective-C

in `viewDidLoad`

```
[tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

Add Following Code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins)]){
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false;
}
```

### Swift

```
if ([UITableView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [[UITableView appearance] setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    [[UITableViewCell appearance] setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    [[UITableViewCell appearance] setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Ashish Kakkad pointed out, it's about the `SeparatorInsets`, I just wanted to add here, that you can also set them in Storyboard, you don't have to do this in code.

Search for Separator inset in interface builder after clicking on the table view
[image: Before]

And change it to `Custom`. Now you can set the Left Inset to `0`

[image: After]

Comment: Maybe just include my screens in your answer as well Ashish for future visitors of this page?

Comment: Ok. then I will add your answer in mine. Thanks! but don't remove your answer. @NilsZiehn