# How to remove separator inset from UITableView in iPad (iOS 9 and above)?

Tags: uitableview, ipad, ios8, ios9, separator

I knew this question is old, so many answers was [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762723/remove-separatorinset-on-ios-8-uitableview-for-xcode-6-iphone-simulator) posted here.

The problem is, the solutions are working fine with iPhone's. But when trying it with iPad, I still faces some issue.

Refer the below images(First one is portrait mode and the second one is in landscape mode).

[image]

[image]

I used the below code in my view controller where I wrote table view's delegate methods.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [tableView setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

   if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
   }
}
```

**Question:**

Is there is any way to remove these left empty space of table view's separator in iPad? Should I include any extra check's beyond the iPhone's working code?

Confused!!

Comment: Can validate this is a thing. I am currently using..
`cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;`
... and it works on iPhone, but not iPad.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770119/ios-8-uitableview-separator-inset-0-not-working . Refer this link and you may get your solution

Comment: @AaronSmentkowski Replace the first line with `cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: cell.bounds.size.width)`

Answer (score 7):

- You may need to set the Table View's
  cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth to NO if you want to customize
  insets or margins. Your mileage may vary, this is not documented very
  well.

**This property only exists in iOS 9 so be sure to check before setting.**

```
if([myTableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setCellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth:)])
{
    myTableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO;
}
```