# iOS - How to set View width equal to TableView Separator width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new in iOS. I have a `View` on top (width 1 px height) and a `UITableView` below the `View`.

Now, The constraint leading and trailing of the View is 10
I have tried to set the Separator Inset for the TableView with value Left is 10 and Right is 10 but it not work well (the view width is not equal to TableView Separator width).

I want to set the width of the `View` equal to the width of the `UITableView Separator`.
What should I do to achieve it? Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: what about constraint `leading` and `trailing` of your `tableView` with `super view`?

Comment: the constraint leading and trailing of your tableView with super view is 0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762723/remove-separatorinset-on-ios-8-uitableview-for-xcode-6-iphone-simulator refer this answer

Comment: Indeed. You can query the `layoutMargins` of your cell and use them to calculate the size and position of the view accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this , You can set the separator inset in your custom tableviewCell class by adding the below method,

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)layoutMargins
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10);
}
```

Then set your view's leading and trailing constraints by 10px.

Comment: Instead of changing the margins, he's better off reading them and adapting his yellow views to those values (that's what's he's asking for, after all). **Still, a pointer in the good direction.** Also, Apple recommends against changing the separator margins.

Answer (score 1):

I think it relate with `margin` property. Make sure you that when you set constraint, you already uncheck this option like this

[image]

And this:
[image]

And in `controller` set `separatorinset`:

```
self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
```

Hope this help!