# How to remove cell separators in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to remove the cell separators in my `UITableView`. This is how my simulator currently looks:

[image]

I have implemented the following line of code in the `viewDidLoad:` method of the `.swift` file of the view controller:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
```

This doesn't seem to be working though.

How do I remove the cell separators?

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RestaurantsTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.nameLabel.text = restaurants[indexPath.row].name
        cell.typeLabel.text = restaurants[indexPath.row].type
        cell.mainImageView.image = UIImage(named: restaurants[indexPath.row].image)

    return cell

}
```

Comment: That row should be enough, I think that you might have some padding between your rows. Post some code for your tableView.

Comment: @RashwanL What code do you want to see?

Comment: Begin with with the function `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @RashwanL I have added this code.

Comment: Are you sure that your image does not have a border?

Comment: @RashwanL How do I check this? It does have `clipsToBounds = true` and `Clip Subviews` enabled.

Comment: Open the image and check :)

Comment: @RashwanL What must I see for it to have a border?

Comment: Upload these three images that you have in your tableView to your question and I´ll take a look.

Comment: @RashwanL I didn't understand the question at first. But no, they don't have a border.

Comment: If UIImageView's layout constraints are okay, I'd say it is cell height a bit larger than image height, so there's some visual space between image and cell bounds. Try correcting your cell height, or set UIImageView to scale image instead of centering it.

Comment: @AnnabelleSykes, I have added an example for you.

Comment: @AlexSkalozub This removed the cell separator, but when I swipe back and forth, the cell height changes.

Comment: @AnnabelleSykes you might want to implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` to control cell height

Comment: @AlexSkalozub Could you show me the code to write?

Comment: Something like `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat { return 100; /* or whatever your height is */ }`. If there's still something wrong with it, check UIImageView constraints again.

Comment: @AlexSkalozub This didn't change anything.

Comment: @AnnabelleSykes you have some error in IB layout then. Can't tell which without seeing it.

Comment: @AlexSkalozub I fixed it with some help! It was because I hadn't set the layout constraints for the cell. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check your layout of cell,especially top and bottom constraints.[image]
2. Check the content view of cell.Did you set the clips to bounds to true?[image]
   [image]

All the above should be checked both in code and IB.

Comment: What layout constraints should there be?

Comment: Also, `clipsToBounds` is set to true in the `viewDidLoad:` method.

Comment: Updated my answer.Check the stretching of content view also.

Comment: What is the superview?

Comment: @AnnabelleSykes What did you mean?The superview of content view?It's the table view cell. The super view of the view with that constraints?Just a image view in the content view.

Comment: In the image you have above of the constraints, for me it says "Cell" instead of "Superview."

Comment: Re-did these constraints, and the problem is fixed! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To hide the separator line you should set the separator insets to zero for each cell. You should add this line in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Comment: This didn't change anything. Thank you though!

Comment: Instead of setting the insets to zero, you should set it with the "right" inset to the width of the table view, i.e., `cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: tableView.bounds.width)`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest giving the cells a random background color instead of white so you can make sure the cell has padding and it's not part of image. If it didn't work you may try setting the inset to zero using both the table and cell reference. Look at this answer for more explanation.

[Remove SeparatorInset on iOS 8 UITableView for XCode 6 iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762723/remove-separatorinset-on-ios-8-uitableview-for-xcode-6-iphone-simulator)

Comment: It is not part of the image. The code in the link, could you please give me in Swift. Thanks!

Comment: Let me try out the code I'll post the swift code in a little bit

Comment: Thank you! This is very much appreciated!